# Why frequency is inversely proportional to time-period?

Tags: waves, time, fourier-transform, frequency, wavelength

1. Why frequency is inversely proportional to time-period?
2. While studying about Fourier transform that shows [frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency) representation. A doubt that came to me was a set of signal with same wavelength but different frequencies. Which one would reach first?
3. Everyone knows since $T \propto \frac {1}{f}$ that the signal with lower frequency would approach first. But could anyone illustrate that because I think even if the signal changes how could that affects it's time at reaching there?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question "same wavelength, different frequencies, which arrives first?": naturally, the one with biggest speed, which is proportional to frequency AND wavelength according to the formula: $$v = \lambda f$$

So, for the same wavelength $\lambda$, the one with bigger frequency $f$ will have bigger speed $v$, thus arriving earlier.

For the question title "Why frequency is inversely proportional to time?", I say, first, that you confuse **time** with **period** here. What you mean is that frequency is inversely proportional to **period**. This is because, if a wave has frequency 10 Hz (which means that, every second, it "cycles" exactly 10 times), then the **period** of each cycle lasts exactly 1/10 seconds. Thus emerges the formula relating frequency with period: $$T = \frac{1}{f} \text{ (units: T = [s], f = [Hz])}$$

Comment: okay.could you say what's the difference between time and time-period?

Comment: **Period:** time a wave takes from one peak to the other (e.g wave with frequency 10 Hz has period 0.1 s). Formula: $T = \frac{1}{f}$ ($f$ in hertz). Do you think that **time** needs a definition?

Comment: okay got it.But whether the time taken for waves having same wavelength but different frequencies be the same(not considering time-period).

Comment: That's what I answered when I wrote above "the one with greatest speed". If the wavelengths $\lambda$ are the same, then the biggest frequency will have the biggest speed. The one with biggest speed, then, will arrive earliest, anywhere. I'll make the answer clearer.

Comment: it "cycles" means does it rotate or does it change it's value?

Comment: Here's an image to make you understand. The arrow in the picture delimits one cycle: http://www.swiftutors.com/admin/photos/wave-period.png

Comment: what's the frequency for the wave in the picture?

Comment: Are you sure that you know what a wave is?

Comment: The frequency of the wave in the picture is 1/(Wave period).

Answer (score 2):

First, the context is a function of time that is *periodic* which means that it is repetitive with repetition period $T$.

$$g(t) = g(t + T)$$

So, if one sampled the function every $T$ seconds, one would get the same value each time.

Now, we have the period of time $T$ which tells how long it takes for the signal to go through one *cycle*.

The inverse question is *how many repetitions (cycles) are there per second?*

We call this number the *frequency* (how *frequent* are the repetitions?) and it's easy to see that the frequency $f$ is just

$$f = \frac{1}{T}$$

Since, for example, if it takes $0.1 s$ for one repetition, the function repeats 10 times in one second and thus, has a frequency of $f = \frac{1}{T} = 10s^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

The very definition of a frequency is the rate at which something occurs over time. Therefore by shortening the time interval in which something occurs you are increasing its frequency, and by increasing the time interval you decrease the frequency. Hence, Frequency is inversely proportional to time.

Comment: can a frequency of complex wave(signal that has many waves) founded by adding the frequency of each wave.

Comment: A complex wave, as you have defined it, does not have a single frequency.

Comment: okay that's right.Is frequency related to the number of occurrences or the rate of change.

Answer (score 0):

The term 'time period' means the time taken for completing one whole oscillation. Whereas frequency is measure of total oscillations divided by time. While describing time period, you are inadvertently choosing that the time computed is for one oscillation. If you are given that an object travels for 2 hours and you have to calculate it's speed without distance given as an information, you cannot do that. But if you are given that an object has travelled 1 km in 2 hour, you can say that the speed is 0.5 kmph. Likewise think of frequency as speed. If you have distance (here oscillation) fixed as one, and you are given time, you can indeed calculate speed( here frequency). So the key point is that while calculating time period, it's definition itself tells that you are calculating it for ONE OSCILLATION. And the definition of frequency itself tells us that we are calculating oscillations PER UNIT TIME. Like speed (frequency) is inversely proportional to time (time period) given fixed distance ( here one oscillation). So you can indeed calculate frequency given oscillation is fixed at one according to definition of time period and only the time period is given as the information.